# Hash keys probe and residual

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, database-internals, query-performance

Say, we have a query like this:

```
select a.*,b.*
from 
a join b
on a.col1=b.col1
and len(a.col1)=10
```

Assuming the above query uses a Hash Join and has a residual, the probe key will be `col1` and the residual will be `len(a.col1)=10`.

But while going through another example, I could see both the probe and the residual to be the same column. Below is an elaboration on what I am trying to say:

**Query:**

```
select *
from T1 join T2 on T1.a = T2.a
```

**Execution plan, with probe and residual highlighted:**

[image]

**Test data:**

```
create table T1 (a int, b int, x char(200))
create table T2 (a int, b int, x char(200))

set nocount on
declare @i int
set @i = 0
while @i < 1000
  begin
      insert T1 values (@i * 2, @i * 5, @i)
    set @i = @i + 1
  end

declare @i int
set @i = 0
while @i < 10000
  begin
    insert T2 values (@i * 3, @i * 7, @i)
    set @i = @i + 1
  end
```

**Question:**

How can a probe and a residual be the same column? Why can't SQL Server use the probe column only? Why does it have to use the same column as a residual to filter rows again?

**References for test data:**

- [Hash Join (Craig Freedman's SQL Server Blog)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/08/10/hash-join/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the join is on a single column typed as `tinyint`, `smallint`, or `integer`* and if both columns are constrained to be `NOT NULL`, the hash function is 'perfect' – meaning there is no chance of a hash collision, and the query processor does not have to check the values again to ensure they really match.

Otherwise, you will see a residual as items in the hash bucket are tested for a match, not just a hash function match.

Your test does not specify `NULL` or `NOT NULL` for the columns (a bad practice, by the way), so it appears you are using a database where `NULL` is the default.

More information in my post [Join Performance, Implicit Conversions, and Residuals](https://sql.kiwi/2011/07/join-performance-implicit-conversions-and-residuals.html) and [Hash Join Execution Internals](http://www.queryprocessor.com/hash-join-execution-internals/) by Dmitry Pilugin.

---

<sub>* Other qualifying types are *bit*, *smalldatetime*, *smallmoney*, and *(var)char(n)* for n = 1 and binary collation</sub>